# Logo looks different on different pages of the website

Tags: html, css

It is really weird thing that I have my logo on all of my pages with the same HTML  and CSS code, but only on the home page it looks pixelated!?

The Html:

```
 <a href="Home.html"><img id="logo" src="../CONTENT/Images/Logo/1Sr2l8а.png" alt="logo"/></a>
<div id="top"></div>


<ul class="nav">
                <li><a  href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a id="products"  href="../product/LAST1.html">Products</a></li>
                <li><a  href="Home.html">Concepts</a></li>
                <li><a  href="../Contact/LAST.php">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
```

The CSS:

```
#logo {
height:142px;
width:142px;
position:fixed; 
margin: auto;   
left: 50%;
margin-left:-71px;  
top:2px;;   
z-index:7000;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your homepage is in a different folder than the rest of your pages.  Your reference to the logo src in the `img` tag is relative.

```
../CONTENT/Images/Logo/1Sr2l8а.png
```

This means the homepage is looking in a different folder for the logo than the other pages.  My guess is that you have a copy of the logo in two places and those images are at a different resolution.

Comment: I have folder for all of my images on the site, and there is not another copies.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your site for us to look at and debug?